# Arch Linux - Installed packages gone after restart

Tags: archlinux, package-managers

I'm trying to install some fonts in Arch Linux (using yay font). The installation is fine, no problem at all. But, after restarting my computer, those installed fonts are gone. I tried to install them again, and restarted. The fonts are always gone.

I also notice that I have to update a lot of packages every morning (using yay). But they are not always the same packages, thus I've thought they may just update so frequently.

I've just started using Arch Linux 2 months ago, and I struggled a lot to install it. Therefore I think I might still leave a lot of errors and mistakes. I need some help please, thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the installed fonts are gone"? Is the package containing the fonts not seem to be installed anymore after the reboot? What actions do you see regarding that package in `/var/log/pacman.log` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved today somehow. Apparently, there were a lot of errors and warnings when I used pacman -Syu, and never read all of them. It has gone like that until now. Then, I got a conflict when updating packages, searched on Google, solved it, rebuilt all packages, and this problem is somehow gone as well.